# Extract first 3 numbers from string

Tags: python, regex

How can I extract first 3 numbers of a string:

in:

`"Box 123 (NO) 456"`

out:

`123`

Comment: More importantly, what if the input is `"Box 1234 (NO) 567"`?

Comment: Numbers or digits ? What if input is ``A 1 BEE 23 SEE 42 D`` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just search for `\d{3}` and grab the first match:

```
match = re.search(r'\d{3}', inputstring)
if match:
    print match.group(0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = "Box 123 (NO) 456"
>>> match = re.search(r'\d{3}', inputstring)
>>> if match:
...     print match.group(0)
... 
123
```

Note that the above *also* matches a substring; if you have a number that is four digits long it'll match the first 3 digits of that number.

Your post is *very* sparse on details; let's presume that the above is not enough but that your numbers are delimited by whitespace, then you can match *exactly* 3 digits by using `\b` anchors:

```
match = re.search(r'\b\d{3}\b', inputstring)
```

which match *only* 3 digits between non-word characters (the start or end of the string, whitespace, punctuation, etc. Anything not a letter or a number or an underscore):

```
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{3}\b', inputstring)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106c4f100>
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{3}\b', "Box 1234")
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{3}\b', "Box 123")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106c4f1d0>
```

Comment: ``match`` isn't ``re.match`` but it isn't a good practice to use a confusing name, anyway

Comment: @eyquem: It's a MatchObject reference, the name is very commonly used.

Comment: _"An error does not become truth by reason of multiplied propagation"_ Gandhi.